# How to debug oracle connection?

Tags: java, database, oracle, tomcat, jdbc

I'm using oracle database. Say I used a jdbc connection in my java web application deployed in a tomcat server running in eclipse, and I forget to close this connection in code after using it. Then, if I stop the tomcat server, will the connection be released and everything is OK, or it will cause some side effects in the oracle database, say some dead connections, and gradually cause the database down?

And how to debug this kind of problems? I mean are there any tools which can let me see the active(and 'dead', if any) connections in my database, and their client address, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could setup Database Connection pooling in Tomcat's META-INF/context.xml file. It can be setup so that abandoned database connections are removed and recycled.

more info:

[Apache Tomcat 7 JNDI Datasource HOW-TO](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html#Database_Connection_Pool_%28DBCP%29_Configurations)

You can query Oracle's v$session and v$process to find out about connections, if they're locked, the name of the process that initiated the connection, the machine name and other info.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in your database

```
select * from v$session
```

and find dead session then

```
kill session 'sid,serial#'
```